# Django adding an about page

Tags: django

I added an about page to my site, it should be a simple mission, but its not working.
The main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
  url(r'^$', include('home.urls', namespace='home', app_name='home')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have a home app, this is home/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
  url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

This is home/views.py:

```
def about(request):
  return render_to_response('pages/about.html')
```

I have the about.html in the home/templates/pages folder.
The index page is being displayed fine, but when I an adding the link to the index page:

```
<li>
     <a href="{% url 'home:about' %}">About</a>
</li>
```

I get the error:

> Reverse for 'about' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$about/']

And I went over the solutions on the site and couldn't find one for me.
Thanks, Keren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url(r'^$', include('home.urls', namespace='home', app_name='home'))
```

I think the line above is the problem, '^$' means exactly empty string, so it doesnt make sense to include something after it. In your home.urls you say '^about/ which means a string that starts with about... 
I would change it to

```
url(r'^', include('home.urls', namespace='home', app_name='home'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the "$":

```
url(r'^', include('home.urls', namespace='home', app_name='home')),
```

The "$" means 'end of line' so your RegEx would check for an empty local part inside your URL which is false for /about